# Does a SharePoint Designer "Wait for Event:" ever expire?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am just wondering if the wait for event: in SharePoint designer ever expires? If there is an event that it is waiting for and it has been several days will it stop waiting and just terminate? or will it last indefinitely?

Thanks for your responses!